# Eliminar espacios del contenido de un input

Tags: javascript, html, input

He estado probando diferentes maneras pero no consigo lo que quiero. Lo que quiero es crear un input con un botón, y al pulsar el botón, elimine los espacios que hay en esa caja de texto y que los guarde en una variable. Esto es:
`<input placeholder="Escriba nombre y apellidos">` y que al escribir el nombre y el/los apellido/s que elimine los espacios entre dichas palabras. El valor luego debería guardarse en una variable. Todo esto usando Javascript, pero todavía no he encontrado resultado. Gracias!

```html
<input id="Textodelinput" placeholder="Escriba nombre y apellido">
<button onclick="juntartexto()">Juntar texto</button>

<script>
var textojuntado="";
function juntartexto() {
 document.getElementById('Textodelinput').innerHTML = textojuntado;
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Por favor revisa cómo preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: He actualizado mi pregunta para que se vea el código. Sin embargo no consigo la manera de juntar el texto del input y guardarlo todo junto en la variable. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Has leido la documentación sobre [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String)? En particular te pueden interesar los métodos [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim) y/o [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split). Y querrás combinarlo con el método [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join) del tipo `Array`. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input id="Textodelinput" placeholder="Escriba nombre y apellido">
<button onclick="juntartexto()">Juntar texto</button>

<script>
var textojuntado="";
function juntartexto() {
    textojuntado = document.getElementById('Textodelinput').value;
    document.getElementById('Textodelinput').value = textojuntado.replace(/\s/g, '');
}
</script>
```

Para eliminar los espacios puedes usar las expresiones Regex dentro de la función replace. La función replace("caracteres a remplazar","caracteres nuevos") tiene dos parametros, el parametro a remplazar y su sustituto.

\s es el regex por los "espacios en blanco", y g es el indicador "global", significando que afecte a todos los "espacios en blanco" (\s) que encuentre.

Las '/' barras antes se ponen al trabajar con regex.

También remarcar, que no estabas obteniendo bien el valor de tu input, ya que para obtener el valor de un input debes usar .value y no .innerHtml. A parte estabas haciendo una asignación al reves, primero debes guardar el valor del  input en la variable textojuntado y luego modificar esa variable y ponerla donde quieras. En mi caso la he vuelto a poner en el input, pero podrias usarla en cualquier otra parte.